# Remove objects from IEnumerable

Tags: c#-4.0, ienumerable

I have this IEnumerable:

```
var collection = from obj in list
                        select new
                        {
                            Title = (string)obj.Element("title"),
                            otherAtt = (string)obj.Element("otherAtt"),
                            ..
                            ..
                            ..
                            ..
                        };
```

And I want to remove all the objects in 'collection' that has duplicate Title. And to leave the last that had a duplicates.

For example:

```
collection = {
    {Title="aaa" ,otherAtt="1" ,....},
    {Title="bbb" ,otherAtt="2" ,....},
    {Title="aaa" ,otherAtt="3" ,....},
    {Title="aaa" ,otherAtt="4" ,....},
    {Title="ccc" ,otherAtt="5" ,....},
    {Title="bbb" ,otherAtt="6" ,....}
}
```

And I need that the filter will cause the collection to look like that:

```
collection = {
    {Title="aaa" ,otherAtt="4" ,....},
    {Title="ccc" ,otherAtt="5" ,....},
    {Title="bbb" ,otherAtt="6" ,....}
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Distinct()` extension method, but you will have to write an IEqualityComparer so that Title is used for the comparison.

I think this is pretty close to what you need: http://forums.asp.net/post/2276937.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The following will work:

```
var noDuplicateTitles = collection
   .GroupBy(obj => obj.Title)
   .Select(group => group.Last())
```

All objects with the same title are grouped, and we take the last item from each group.